# Bad credentials Magento extension manager

Tags: magento, composer

I have tried to login into magento marketplace through the Extension Manager by using the Public and Private key which I copied from my account in the marketplace. But I always get BAD CREDENTIALS. I thought it has to do with Composer.Composer was installed in magento2 directory and then moved to `/usr/local/bin/composer`. I changed the owner of composer from `root` to `www-data`. Even created an `auth.json` with my keys from marketplace in the magento2 directory. I still get BAD CREDENTIALS.

Does it have to do with how composer is installed and configured? Anyone?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not copying an extra space character either at the beginning or the end of the key. You can verify this by first copying the key to a text editor like GEdit.

Notice the extra space in the example below which normally won't be visible in normal text.

```
Hello World
 Hello World
```

Comment: @PabloBianchi I think this is a possible answer. I have also faced the same issue while copying credentials from emails, a space is also copied at the end which then brings the 'wrong credentials' error. It just needs some tweaking.